# Firebase: Guardar UID en la base de datos

Tags: android, base-de-datos, firebase

quisiera saber como puedo guardar el uid que genera para cada usuario en la misma base de datos?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera que ese uid se guardara debajo del campo sexo, es decir que se guardara su propio uid en cada usuario que cree.

Y una consulta mas: Estoy tratando de realizar la funcion de seguir y seguidores, quisiera que yo al darle click en el boton seguir se agregara en ambos perfiles segun el caso: perfil 1 lo esta siguiendo perfil 2 y perfil 2 esta siguiendo a perfil 1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siguiendo a tu respuesta que es correcta, deberias comprobar que el userID no sea null antes de mandarlo a la base de datos, ya que en cualquier caso puede llegar a serlo, solo agregando una comprobacion antes de mandar a la base de datos estaria bien.

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

if(mAuth != null ){

String user_id = mAuth.getUid();
 DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Usuario");
        DatabaseReference currentUserDB = databaseReference.child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        currentUserDB.child("uid").setValue(user_id);
}
```

Para la segunda parte de los seguidores, los podes almacenar bajo el nodo de cada usuario con una referencia al usuario que lo sigue, de esta forma podes saber el perfil de cada uno y luego con un `getChildrenCount()` podrias saber la cantidad de seguidores de un usuario

Por ejemplo, esta es una estructura que habia hecho para una app similar a lo que buscas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aca podes ver que el nodo followed-by solo guarda las UID de los usuarios que me siguen, y follows guarda las UID de los usuarios que sigo, luego, si yo quiero acceder al perfil de cada uno, solo basta con ir al nodo de ese usuario con ese dato y buscar su meta data (nombre, bio, etc) .

De esta forma, tambien puedo agarrar y hacer un `getChildrenCount()` de cada nodo, tanto como followed-by (para conocer la cantidad de personas que me siguen) como en el de follows (para saber a cuantos sigo)

Comment: Excelente tu respuesta, viendo tu imagen puedo percatarme que tomas el uid de la persona que te sigue o sigues, pero como lo colocas como el "referente del campo?", por ejemplo tienes un campo llamado "name", pero como pones el uid que aparezca siendo un campo?

Comment: lo podes hacer poniendo child(followerId).setValue(true);

Comment: Perfecto, elimine mi comentario porque ya pude hacer lo otro que preguntaba.

Comment: Tengo una consulta con tu imagen, como sabras ya se como tomar el uid del usuario que esta conectado, pero si tengo dos usuarios, y usuario activo, sigue a usuario 2... como obtengo el uid del usuario 2? Porque puede haber miles de usuarios, como puedo definer que cada vez que se le de seguir a un usuario, obtenga el uid exacto de ese usuario?

Comment: Vas a implementar un buscador para encontrar a usuario 2 , usuario 1 ya está conectado y tenés el uid , para buscar a usuario 2 vas a hacer un foto recorriendo a todos los usuarios menos el tuyo  , obtienes todos los datos y con getKey obtienes la ley del usuario que seleccionaste

Comment: Entendi mas o menos, tienes algun codigo con que me pueda guiar o se parezca a lo que estoy haciendo... disculpa que moleste tanto pero me estoy apenas adentrando en firebase y poco a poco voy tomando los conceptos de una base de datos no sql.

Comment: No me molesta para nada, busca tvac studio en youtube

Answer (score 2):

```
String user_id = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Usuario");
        DatabaseReference currentUserDB = databaseReference.child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        currentUserDB.child("uid").setValue(user_id);
```

Asi pude resolver el como obtener el uid y añadirlo a la base de datos.