# ¿Cómo guardar en Firestore el ID del usuario que ha iniciado sesión?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-auth

Estoy intentado guardar datos en Cloud Firestore con estas reglas pero no puedo

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow only authenticated content owners access
    match /some_collection/{userId}/{documents=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId
    }
  }
}
```

Cuando utilizo las reglas que solo incluyan las de authentication funciona, pero el error ocurre cuando intento usar las que ya pase, que es solo para que el usuario que creo esos datos pueda editarlos o leerlos.

Me tira este error

> 2021-06-04 03:53:16.561 9716-9872/com.amdevops.recetas W/Firestore: (23.0.1) [WriteStream]: (a32b903) Stream closed with status: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}.

> 2021-06-04 03:53:16.607 9716-9872/com.amdevops.recetas W/Firestore: (23.0.1) [Firestore]: Write failed at ingredientes/tNFBUUTgVg8R3xwLuH6M: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

Logicamente es porque no tengo el uid del user y tampoco se como pasarlo a la base de datos, como haria?

Esta es la consulta

```
class FirebaseRepo {

    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    fun setIngredienteData(nombre:String,precio:Int,cantidad:Int,unidad:String){

        val ingredienteHashMap = hashMapOf(
            "nombre" to nombre,
            "precio" to precio,
            "cantidad" to cantidad,
            "unidad" to unidad)
        db.collection("ingredientes")
            .add(ingredienteHashMap).addOnCompleteListener {
                if(it.isSuccessful){
                    //
                }else{
                    //
                }
            }

    }
}
```

Habia visto en esta otra [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225447/firebase-guardar-uid-en-la-base-de-datos) que se hace con un `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` pero tampoco se dónde ponerlo ni cómo enviarlo a la base para que me deje guardarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El id del usuario actual se puede obtener así

```
val uid = Firebase.auth.currentUser!!.uid
```

Al hacer esto
`db.collection("ingredientes").add(ingredienteHashMap)`
estás creando un documento que tendrá esta ruta `ingredientes/randomId`, que no coincide para nada con la ruta `/some_collection/{userId}/{documents=**}` que está en tu regla de seguridad.

La solución más simple es incluir el uid en la ruta. Por ejemplo así

```
db.collection("usuarios/$uid/ingredientes").add(ingredienteHashMap)
```

Entonces, para que funcione bastaría con corregir el nombre de la colección en tu regla de seguridad

```
match /usuarios/{userId}/{documents=**}
```

La otra opción es agregar el uid en un campo del documento

```
    val ingredienteHashMap = hashMapOf(
        "nombre" to nombre,
        "precio" to precio,
        "cantidad" to cantidad,
        "unidad" to unidad,
        "usuario" to uid,
    )
    db.collection("ingredientes").add(ingredienteHashMap)
```

Pero tendrías que cambiar la regla de seguridad a algo como esto

```
match /ingredientes/{id} {
  allow create: if request.auth != null;
  allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.usuario;
}
```

Comment: Gracias Sinner! Me funcionó de maravila! Esta base de datos es para ponerla en un Recycler View, para seguir con esto tendria que hacer otra pregunta o por aca?

En el caso de que sea por aca, cual seria la forma correcta de recibir los datos para plasmarlos en el Recycler View? El adapter y todo eso lo ya lo tengo hecho y funciona bien, lo tengo poblado con datos predefinidos por mi a modo de prueba, ahora solo me falta conectar la base de datos al recycler view, supongo que se hara con un for para recorrer los documentos y sus datos